# Smooth background opacity change on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, opacity

I'm trying to gradually change the opacity of two different elements on scroll: the first one (the text) should move up and fade out, while the second (the background) should fade in. The code I've got so far works and does what I expect it to do, but the animation definitely isn't smooth enough in Chrome and Firefox (Safari seems to handle it much better).

JS:

```
var scroll = window.requestAnimationFrame ||
             window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
             window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
             window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
             window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
             // IE Fallback
             function(callback){ window.setTimeout(callback, 1000/60) };

var lastPosition = -1;
var textdiv = $('#text');
var BG = $('#bg');

function animateBG(){  

  scrollTop = window.pageYOffset;
  if (lastPosition == scrollTop) {
    scroll(animateBG);
    return false;
  } else { lastPosition = scrollTop; }

  scroll(animateBG);

  if (scrollTop <601) {
    var opacity = 1-(scrollTop/600);
    textdiv.css('-webkit-transform',"translate3d(0px, " + -(scrollTop/4) + "px, 0px)").css('opacity', opacity);
    BG.css('opacity', 1-opacity);
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="foo">
  <div id="bg"></div>
  <div id="text">Yada yada</div>
</div>
```

If I only keep the text animated without the opacity change on the background, things remain buttery smooth. When I add the opacity change on the background div however, the animation gets bumpy in Chrome and Firefox, and less smooth in Safari (albeit acceptable).

I read somewhere that Safari tends to round numbers. Is it what makes it run the script smoother? If so, should I round the opacity variable, and how?

Thanks!

UPDATE:

[Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/P87TW/2/) It seems that the animation is only bumpy when the parent div #foo has a bitmap background (which I want it to have): I tried setting the background of #foo to a plain color, and the animation is smooth again. :-/

UPDATE 2: I was wrong about the plain background. I tried it with my actual page, and it doesn't change anything. Size seems to matter however: I gave #bg a smaller size, and the animation is smoother. I really it to be 100% wide and 100% high, though.

Comment: Oh a JSFiddle would be great to help you out!  http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Right! I updated my post with the link.